# How do I get ROS to work on Chakra?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install ROS on Chakra Linux.
Following the installation instructions of http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Arch it aborted the installation because it didn´t detect the os. So I had to add -n for the desktop-full installation to get it work.
Now, whenever I try to use rosdep install it keeps saying:
rosdep ABORTING.  Failed to detect OS: Could not detect OS, tried ['rosdep_test_os', 'debian', 'ubuntu', 'ubuntu', 'opensuse', 'fedora', 'rhel', 'arch', 'osx', 'osxbrew', 'gentoo', 'cygwin', 'freebsd'].
How can I manually tell it, that the os is arch and make it install the necessary dependencies?

Additional info: I am using Linux 3.5.6-1-CHAKRA 64bit (Archimedes)

I hope someone can help me with this problem..

Mareike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47339/how-do-i-get-ros-to-work-on-chakra?/) by [mareikep](https://answers.ros.org/users/3516/mareikep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-11-02**:
What is chakra linux? Never heard of it ... do you have a link to it? Thanks.

**Comment by [mareikep](https://answers.ros.org/users/3516/mareikep/) on 2012-11-03**:
Chakra Linux is based on Arch Linux.. see http://chakra-project.org/ (you can find some more information under "About Chakra")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_OS_OVERRIDE is likely what you need: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0